# Finding status if MDB is running

Tags: ejb, mbeans, open-liberty

I want to use mbeans on startup of j2ee application to check if all the MDBs are running and jms specification has been activated.

Any pointers will be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know of to do this would be to use the ServerEndpointControl MBean. This is a Liberty specific MBean for controlling the input sources for work into the runtime. This can also be used to get status on http listeners.

The best place to find the Javadoc for the MBean is [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.liberty.doc/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.kernel.service_1.0-javadoc/com/ibm/websphere/kernel/server/ServerEndpointControlMBean.html). To find out if an MBean is running you call the isPaused method providing the MDB name which is defined as:

```
ApplicationName#ModuleName#BeanName
```

if the MDB is running it'll return false.